# Revisited: Python Mocking a function from an imported module

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

Python 3.9.
In my unittest, I want to instantiate ServiceProvider, but it has to use mock_get_service in the test, not the imported get_service, since this makes network calls.

I have worked through many solutions, including the original named above, with no success. Every time, the original get_service is called and crashes.

app_module:

```
from services import get_service

class ServiceProvider()

    def find_service(self, service_id):
        return get_service(service_id)
```

unittest_module:

```
from app_module import ServiceProvider

def mock_get_service(service_id):
    """ Test method: return the named service. """
    if service_id == 'ServiceA':
        service = ServiceA()
    else:
        service = ServiceB()
    return service

class Test_ServiceProvider(unittest.TestCase):
    def test1_find_service(self):
        with patch('app_module.get_service') as mocked_get_service:
            mocked_get_service.side_effect = mock_get_service
            server = ServiceProvider()
            serv = server.find_service('ServiceA')
            self.assertIsInstance(serv, ServiceA)
```

Comment: In my effort to simplify my code for this post, I miss-named  the first def as get_service, it would have been clearer if I had called it find_service, as later named. Sorry.

Comment: You can read https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch for more information about how to mock things. I find your question a bit hard to follow since there are several similarly-named functions in different files, and I'm not sure what you've tried so far.

Comment: I understand your problem and I have simplified the question.  I think I am trying to mock get_service imported into app_module, which is were I think the call in ServiceProvider will go. I have tried many arrangements without success. I greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `patch.object` when mocking a member of an object.

```py
with patch.object(ServiceProvider, "get_service", side_effect=mock_get_service):
    # your test case will use mock_get_service() when ServiceProvider.get_service() is called
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work on the preferred code. I have clarified the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
from app_module import ServiceProvider

def mock_get_service(service_id):
    """ Test method: return the named service. """
    if service_id == 'ServiceA':
        service = ServiceA()
    else:
        service = ServiceB()
    return service

class Test_ServiceProvider(unittest.TestCase):
    def test1_find_service(self):
        with patch.object(ServiceProvider, "get_service", side_effect=mock_get_service):

            mocked_get_service.side_effect = mock_get_service
            server = ServiceProvider()
            serv = server.find_service('ServiceA')
            self.assertIsInstance(serv, ServiceA)
```

Comment: ServiceProvider doesn't have a get_service attribute, get_service is an imported method.  Maybe mock won't do what I want.